# TPA0253: Help Understanding Mono Output

Tags: audio, high-pass-filter, stereo

I'm working on implementing an audio amplifier into a circuit design, and I am trying to understand the output configuration for the speaker using the [TPA0253](https://www.ti.com/general/docs/suppproductinfo.tsp?distId=10&gotoUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fgpn%2Ftpa0253). I will be using a 8 ohm, 1W speaker for my design. For my project, I plan on using only a mono speaker with the input being stereo. So I chose this IC because I wanted something that would easily convert stereo to mono.

From what I understand, the output to the speaker uses a highpass filter. If I was to use a single speaker without a headphone connection, how would I draw the schematic, and would I need a highpass filter on both the mono+ and mono- pins?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *If I was to use a single speaker without a headphone connection, how
> would I draw the schematic*

[image]

Page 2 of the data sheet above shows you how to do this (see above).

Or if you want to use your schematic look for the nodes Lo/Mo- and Ro/Mo+ and connect the node called STEREO/MONO to Vdd via 100 kohm.

Comment: For the filtering, would I connect the speaker as shown in the diagram? At the bare minimum, would I just need a capacitor in series with the Mo+ pin and the positive terminal of the speaker, and just connect the negative terminal of the speaker to Mo-? Sorry, I'm not very experienced in audio circuits.

Comment: Just connect the speaker as shown in the diagram.